# Nativscript getRootView() not working

Tags: angular, nativescript

In my root component I am trying to take screenshoot like this:

```
private getImage(v) {
        if (topmost().android) {
            const view = android.activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            const bmp = android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            var source = new imageSource.ImageSource();
            view.source.setNativeSource(bmp);
            return source;
        }
    }
```

But I getting error that I cannot call getWindow function on undefined...

```
JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWindow' of undefined
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is this angular or android question?

Comment: It is more Nativescript, but I using Angular as well

Answer (score 1):

use `application.android.foregroundActivity` or `application.android.context`. this will help you get reference to current activity. and then you can use

```
    import * as application from "application";
    const view = application.android.foregroundActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    const bmp = android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

here is playground demo link if you need it:https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=cmvjgq

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to set root view opacity to 0 and than take screenshot behind application?

Comment: i didn't get it what is your question.